# Sensor to detect movement of object on a horizontal wire

Tags: accelerometer, tracking, movement

I am looking on how to build a solution to track movement of an item clipped to a horizontal wire. It has been suggested I could do with with an accelerometer and Arduino. I want to detect any movement, whether the object is rattled or slid. If slid, it would only move a couple mm at a time. The item on the wire is about 1cm width. It has a tag at the bottom so it's possible to attach something to it.

Am I on the right track with thinking an accelerometer is how I would do this? If so, would something like a 2-4g accelorometer do the job?

Comment: A great deal of information is missing. What are the overall physical dimensions of the object and wire? Exactly what kind of "movement" do you want to detect...direction? acceleration? Likewise for sliding...the displacement doesn't matter if the acceleration is low and you want to use an accelerometer. What causes the item to move? Will the electronics be on the item or somewhere else? If somewhere else, how far away? What is the smallest movement you want to detect (and don't say "any" movement, that is meaningless).

Comment: You can make or buy a wireless (Bluetooth Low Energy) module with an accelerometer, that is coin cell powered, about 2cm diameter and a few mm thick. You’ll need a smartphone, or PC, or other gateway to get the event to where you want it monitored. A sensor with a gyroscope would be even more sensitive, but takes more power. I think the accelerometer alone would be sufficient.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of information, this is my first ever electronics project and I am missing much of the lingo to express what I need. I am trying to detect when an animal interacts with an object, I don't know how to qualify amount of movement (I can find this out if you tell me how it should be expressed) nor have I figured answers to the other questions yet. @MarkLeavitt the wireless module sounds like a possibility - is it possible to give some example products?